# How to see code not coverage block

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual studio Premium 2012.

In unit testing, It shows only number of blocks that's not covered, But it doesn't show which block I doesn't cover.

In visual studio 2010, it shows number of blocks that's not covered and also which block I didn't cover in different color.

How to know which block I didn't cover ? How to use VS premium 2012 to know which block I didn't cover ?

Comment: Got this error today in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.
The same correction suggested worked:
run `devenv /resetuserdata`
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done some research for you and I got something you might find useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628(v=vs.110).aspx

Unit test:

|
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264975(v=vs.110).aspx

This Link shows how to display block which are not beeing covered...

|
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159340.aspx

For VS 12.

I hope this can help you solve your problem..

Comment: Yes. I've tried everything. But when I clicked "show code coverage coloring", nothing happens. Did I miss anything ?

In this path, I've chosen appropriate color for the links.. But nothing happens.
" Tools, Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors, Show settings for: Text Editor. Under Display Items"

Comment: @JeevaJsb, you didn't by any chance upgrade from VS Professional to Premium - I had this same problem and had to run `devenv /resetuserdata` to get it working.

Comment: @StephenByrne,Thank you so much. I've tried so long time . I didn't get any answer from any post. But you've kicked off. Thank you

Comment: Yes, It's now working.

Post below answer as answer. I'll mark that as answer. It'll help some people

@JeevaJsb, you didn't by any chance upgrade from VS Professional to Premium - I had this same problem and had to run devenv /resetuserdata to get it working

Comment: Got this error today in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.
The same correction suggested worked:
run `devenv /resetuserdata`
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Test -> Analyze Code Coverage -> All test. Once that is done you open the Code Coverage Results window (under Test -> Windows) click Show Code Coverage Coloring.